# Ошибки в попытке получить список для поля ManyToMany. JPA+Hibernate

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, jpa

У меня есть два класса -- фильм и автор. Между ними есть двусторонная связь ManyToMany. Фильм содержит в себе список авторов. Я пытаюсь реализовать все это через EntityManager. Цель - получить список авторов для конкретного фильма.

Class movie:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MOVIE")
@Data
public class Movie {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String movieName;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
      name = "movie_authors",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))
  private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

  public void addAuthor(Author author) {
    authors.add(author);
  }
}
```

Class author:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Author {

  @Id
  private String name;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
  private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Метод, где я создаю фильмы и авторов, потом добавляю в базу данных.

```
public void saveMovie() {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.setId(1L);
    movie.setMovieName("The Godfather");

    Author author = new Author();
    author.setName("Privet");
    movie.addAuthor(author);

    Author author1 = new Author();
    author1.setName("Lol");
    movie.addAuthor(author1);

    em.persist(author);
    em.persist(author1);
    em.persist(movie);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
  }
```

Затем я пытаюсь получить фильм вместе со списком авторов.

```
  public Movie getMovie(Long movieId) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    Movie movie = em.find(Movie.class, movieId);
    Hibernate.initialize(movie.getAuthors());
    em.detach(movie);
    return movie;
  }
```

Но я всегда получаю такую ошибку. Если же я убираю строку с Hibernate.initialize(), то уже идет LazyException.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:4303)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:3343)
at Movie.hashCode(Movie.java:9)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607)
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355)
at Author.hashCode(Author.java:10)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607)
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:352)
```

Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема была в использовании Lombok, а именно в аннотации @Data, так как она создавала рекурсивную связь со списком(toString, HashCode, equals)